# Angular2/ Material2 - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

as i updated to the new Angular2/Material2 alpha 8.1 i ran into several errors.
First of all the newest package seems to need Typescript 2.0 (use of "readonly") - so i installed typescript 2.0 beta.

But now I get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" whenever I access the page.

Is there anything I need to set/change in Typescript 2.0 ?

This is my tsconfig.json (tried target: es5 aswell...):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {   
    "lib": [ "es6", "es5", "es2015", "dom" ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "bin",
    "node_modules",   
    "wwwroot/dist"
  ]
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like you're generating ES6 from your TypeScript and sending that straight to the browser without any additional preprocessing. Most browsers today have no idea what to do with an `import` statement.

Comment: That could be the problem.. when I set target to es5, i get the same error, but with some 3rd party packages (as my code seems to be es5..). Could you give me a hint for what to use for additional processing?

Comment: The 3rd party packages you're using also need to be transpiled to ES5. I use [JSPM](http://jspm.io/) for this kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I got 2 things wrong:

1.) [This answer fixed part of the problem](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1176)

2.) And... dumb me: I cannot tell why, but I had the wrong import statements,

instead of

```
import {MdButtonToggleModule} from '@angular2-material/button-toggle';
```

I used

```
import {MdButtonToggleModule} from '@angular2-material/button-toggle/button-toggle';
```

what of course pointed to the wrong module format (es2015).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem, you need to setup your packages, and associate to the umd version of the js files....  see if this helps.

within system-config.ts

```
const packages: any = {
....
  "@angular2-material/button": { 
      main: "button.umd.js", 
      defaultExtension: "js", 
      format: "cjs" 
    },
....
};
```

import is valid ES6 but since browsers are still more on the ES5 side (at least on what modules refer), import is not a valid token. umd bundles don't use import.

Answer (score 1):

It's a part of Breaking Changes with alpha-8

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md